# Pandas str.split by dash

Tags: python, pandas

I have problem splitting Pandas series by dash:

```
df['age'].head()

75)[1]Reichenberg, Sudetenland, Germany (present-day Liberec             
52) orJanuary 20, 1967 (age 51)(sources differ                                             
45–46                                                                                      
40–41                                                                                      
52)St.Thomas, Virgin Islands (United States of America
```

When I apply:

```
df['age'] = df['age'].str.split(')', n=1, expand=True)[0]
```

I correctly get:

```
df['age'].head()

75           
52                                           
45–46                                                                                      
40–41                                                                                      
52
```

But when I try to split by dash, it doesn't split the results:

```
df['age'] = df['age'].str.split('-', n=1, expand=True)[0]
df['age'].head()

75           
52                                           
45–46                                                                                      
40–41                                                                                      
52
```

Comment: `–` is an en dash.

Comment: omg it's different dash, thanks